# Can't join Windows 7 to SBS 2008 Domain .. Could do with some help?(logs posted)

Tags: windows-7, domain, domain-controller, windows-sbs-2008

We have been getting this error for a while now while we try to connect a new windows 7 x64professional to a SBS 2008 domain.
I have done

> net use \\Domaincontroller.internaldomain.local\ipc$ /u:internaldomain.local\administrator password

And it comes back with the following:

> System error 71 has occurred.
>   No more connections can be made to this remote computer at this time because the
>   re are already as many connections as the computer can accept.

The Server is running Small Business Server 2008 and I was under the impression we didn't have to install CAL's on the server itself but  just to keep a record of them?
There is only one domain controller in our network but there is 2 server 2003 servers

Reading the netsetup.log :

```
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449 NetpDoDomainJoin
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449 NetpMachineValidToJoin: 'NEWCOMPUTER'
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449     OS Version: 6.1
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449     Build number: 7601 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.110622-1506)
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449     ServicePack: Service Pack 1
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449     SKU: Windows 7 Professional
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449 NetpDomainJoinLicensingCheck: ulLicenseValue=1, Status: 0x0
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449 NetpGetLsaPrimaryDomain: status: 0x0
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449 NetpMachineValidToJoin: status: 0x0
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449 NetpJoinDomain
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449     Machine: NEWCOMPUTER
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449     Domain: InternalDomain.local
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449     MachineAccountOU: (NULL)
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449     Account: InternalDomain.local\administrator
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449     Options: 0x425
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449 NetpLoadParameters: loading registry parameters...
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449 NetpLoadParameters: DNSNameResolutionRequired not found, defaulting to '1' 0x2
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449 NetpLoadParameters: DomainCompatibilityMode not found, defaulting to '0' 0x2
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449 NetpLoadParameters: status: 0x2
09/05/2011 16:20:34:449 NetpValidateName: checking to see if 'InternalDomain.local' is valid as type 3 name
09/05/2011 16:20:34:574 NetpCheckDomainNameIsValid [ Exists ] for 'InternalDomain.local' returned 0x0
09/05/2011 16:20:34:574 NetpValidateName: name 'InternalDomain.local' is valid for type 3
09/05/2011 16:20:34:574 NetpDsGetDcName: trying to find DC in domain 'InternalDomain.local', flags: 0x40001010
09/05/2011 16:20:34:683 NetpLoadParameters: loading registry parameters...
09/05/2011 16:20:34:683 NetpLoadParameters: DNSNameResolutionRequired not found, defaulting to '1' 0x2
09/05/2011 16:20:34:683 NetpLoadParameters: DomainCompatibilityMode not found, defaulting to '0' 0x2
09/05/2011 16:20:34:683 NetpLoadParameters: status: 0x2
09/05/2011 16:20:34:683 NetpDsGetDcName: status of verifying DNS A record name resolution for 'DOMAINCONTROLLER.InternalDomain.local': 0x0
09/05/2011 16:20:34:683 NetpDsGetDcName: found DC '\\DOMAINCONTROLLER.InternalDomain.local' in the specified domain
09/05/2011 16:20:34:683 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: NetpDsGetDcName returned: 0x0
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 NetUseAdd to \\DOMAINCONTROLLER.InternalDomain.local\IPC$ returned 71
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 NetpJoinDomain: status of connecting to dc '\\DOMAINCONTROLLER.InternalDomain.local': 0x47
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: Function exits with status of: 0x47
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 NetpDoDomainJoin: status: 0x47
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 -----------------------------------------------------------------
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 NetpDoDomainJoin
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 NetpMachineValidToJoin: 'NEWCOMPUTER'
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792     OS Version: 6.1
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792     Build number: 7601 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.110622-1506)
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792     ServicePack: Service Pack 1
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792     SKU: Windows 7 Professional
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 NetpDomainJoinLicensingCheck: ulLicenseValue=1, Status: 0x0
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 NetpGetLsaPrimaryDomain: status: 0x0
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 NetpMachineValidToJoin: status: 0x0
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 NetpJoinDomain
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792     Machine: NEWCOMPUTER
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792     Domain: InternalDomain.local
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792     MachineAccountOU: (NULL)
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792     Account: InternalDomain.local\administrator
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792     Options: 0x427
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 NetpLoadParameters: loading registry parameters...
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 NetpLoadParameters: DNSNameResolutionRequired not found, defaulting to '1' 0x2
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 NetpLoadParameters: DomainCompatibilityMode not found, defaulting to '0' 0x2
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 NetpLoadParameters: status: 0x2
09/05/2011 16:20:34:792 NetpValidateName: checking to see if 'InternalDomain.local' is valid as type 3 name
09/05/2011 16:20:34:901 NetpCheckDomainNameIsValid [ Exists ] for 'InternalDomain.local' returned 0x0
09/05/2011 16:20:34:901 NetpValidateName: name 'InternalDomain.local' is valid for type 3
09/05/2011 16:20:34:901 NetpDsGetDcName: trying to find DC in domain 'InternalDomain.local', flags: 0x40001010
09/05/2011 16:20:35:010 NetpLoadParameters: loading registry parameters...
09/05/2011 16:20:35:010 NetpLoadParameters: DNSNameResolutionRequired not found, defaulting to '1' 0x2
09/05/2011 16:20:35:010 NetpLoadParameters: DomainCompatibilityMode not found, defaulting to '0' 0x2
09/05/2011 16:20:35:010 NetpLoadParameters: status: 0x2
09/05/2011 16:20:35:010 NetpDsGetDcName: status of verifying DNS A record name resolution for 'DOMAINCONTROLLER.InternalDomain.local': 0x0
09/05/2011 16:20:35:010 NetpDsGetDcName: found DC '\\DOMAINCONTROLLER.InternalDomain.local' in the specified domain
09/05/2011 16:20:35:010 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: NetpDsGetDcName returned: 0x0
09/05/2011 16:20:35:151 NetUseAdd to \\DOMAINCONTROLLER.InternalDomain.local\IPC$ returned 71
09/05/2011 16:20:35:151 NetpJoinDomain: status of connecting to dc '\\DOMAINCONTROLLER.InternalDomain.local': 0x47
09/05/2011 16:20:35:151 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: Function exits with status of: 0x47
09/05/2011 16:20:35:151 NetpDoDomainJoin: status: 0x47
```

But I can't find any information anywhere that helps.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: We are experiencing the same thing with our VDI environment. When rolling out 10 desktops, only 7/8 will work. The others will show as broken. Upon logging into these broken desktops we discover the same error NetpJoinDomain: status of connecting to dc '\\XXXXXXXXXXXXX': 0x47
NetpJoinDomainOnDs: Function exits with status of: 0x47
NetpDoDomainJoin: status: 0x47

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your clocks. Is your clock on the Windows 7 computer within 5 minutes of the clock on the DC? Are they in the same time zone?

Comment: I had forgotten to update this thread .. after an hour of posting this problem .. went on to another workstation with a separate problem saw that there was 10mins difference in time.
Updated clock to match DC and worked. Wouldn't have thought to check times

Comment: Just a quick note;
After many years of being a sys admin now .. the timezone are irrelevant as it's based on UTC.

Answer (score 0):

A 0x00000047 message translates to:

"No more connections can be made to this remote computer at this time because there are already as many connections as the computer can accept."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can view the sessions on the server using the command:  NET SESSION

or also in Computer Management.